# Stop words Removal in Lucene

Tags: lucene

How to remove stop words in Lucene for the given String "This is the chemical orientation"

Answer (score 0):

I think that Lucene's [StopFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/StopFilter.html) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you should use standardAnalyser ,that knows about certain token types, lowercases, removes stop words, ...
example of creating an IndexWriter with standardAnalyser:

```
public  IndexWriter Indexer(String dir) throws IOException {
    IndexWriter writer;
    Directory indexDir = FSDirectory.open(new File(dir).toPath());
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    IndexWriterConfig cfg = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
    cfg.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
    writer = new IndexWriter(indexDir, cfg);
    return writer;
}
```